# Updating to ASP.NET 5 Beta 8: Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection vs. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I updated from ASP.NET 5 Beta 6 to ASP.NET 5 Beta 8 and have several problems adding services to `IServiceCollection`.

Reading the commit messages I noticed, that the namespace `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection` was renamed to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` so I did the same.

Now I have the following problems:

- `services.ConfigureAntiforgery()` can't be found
- `services.AddCookieAuthentication()` can't be found
- `services.AddSession()` can't be found
- `services.AddSession(Action<SessionOptions> configure)` can't be found
- `services.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Action<IdentityOptions> configure)` can't be found
- `services.AddDefaultTokenProvider()` can't be found
- `services.AddMvc()` can't be found

These extension methods are still available in the old namespace, but others like `services.AddDataProtection()` are not.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Weird, for example [`AddMvc`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) is now under the new namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. You sure you followed the [installation steps ](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html)? Including `dnvm upgrade`?

Comment: According to [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/7976b3e2c2bbe402891f5f62431676481c9d00bf/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) it's not.

Comment: Same with [AntiForgery](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/f2d5c352f2507ff35ee558955355e0ab79787c2a/samples/AntiforgerySample/Startup.cs).

Comment: Interesting, I was looking at the latest [MvcServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) in github, which uses `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. Last change on that file seems to be 17 days ago _Renaming Microsoft.Framework.* -> Microsoft.Extensions.*_

Comment: Your link seems old. Latest change shown in your link for MvcServiceCollectionExtensions seems to be Sep 2?

Comment: That's the source I get when I click on the beta-8-release's commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection` -> `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` change was added after beta8 (release).

Undo your naming changes and it should work.

Comment: OMG! I started updating again and it just works. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: More explanation might help future users.  What are these two things?